# Context menu commands in an Observable Collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, contextmenu

I am new to WPF and am trying to bind a context menu to an ObservableCollection of models. I am able to get the context menu to display but I can't get the commands to fire. Here is my code

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuList}">
  <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
      <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
      <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value ="{Binding Children}" />
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuCommand}"/>
    </Style>
  </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

In the View Model I have

```
    public class MenuItemViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection Children { get; set; }
        public ICommand MenuCommand;

        public MenuItemViewModel(string name, ObservableCollection pChildren, ICommand pCommand)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Children = pChildren;
            this.MenuCommand = pCommand;
        }
    }
```

and I populate the collection

```
public void AddContextMenuItems()
{
        this.ContextMenuList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();

        ICommand pCommand = new ActionCommand(() => this.ChangeChartType());
        MenuItemViewModel ohlc = new MenuItemViewModel("OHLC",null,pCommand);

        MenuItemViewModel candlestick = new MenuItemViewModel("CandleStick");
        ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel> chartTypeColl = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>();
        chartTypeColl.Add(ohlc);
        chartTypeColl.Add(candlestick);

        this.ContextMenuList.Add(new MenuItemViewModel("ChartType",chartTypeColl));
}
```

I don't see the ChangeChartType method ever get triggered, what I am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try making your `MenuCommand` a property (`public ICommand MenuCommand{ get; set; }`)? You cannot bind to fields. Besides how do you want it to work? Child should call the command of the parent or it's own command, when it has no children?

Comment: I would like to make the MenuCommand a part of the model  in  the ObservableCollection. My context menu will eventually have a number of options and I would like to have the menu items bound to an observable collection  of models. So each MenuItem's command would be bound to the ICommand in the Model. Is that possible ?

Comment: For starters you must change `MenuItemCommand` into property, like I mentioned before. WPF does not allow for binding to fields. Did you do that?

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood your answer before. Yes it worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change MenuCommand field to property

```
public ICommand MenuCommand { get; set; }
```

Hope this work for you. I haven't tried this though.

Comment: Har07 is correct, make MenuCommand as Property, it should not be a variable, WPF will only search for public properties in the ViewModdel nothing else

Comment: @Kumareshan it's not true that _WPF will only search for public properties in the ViewModdel nothing else_. You can bind for example to `DataTable` by specifying `Path`. Read more about [Binding Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx)